# Ставится ли тут запятая? Почему?

Tags: пунктуация

> ***Точно священную реликвию***, носили они под пехотной шинелью свои полинявшие застиранные тельняшки.

Почему ставится запятая? Или же не ставится? Объясните попроще. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

**Точно священную реликвию** носили они под пехотной шинелью свои полинявшие застиранные тельняшки.

***Точно священную реликвию (как священную реликвию)***:  оборот со  значением "в качестве" не обособляется, на него падает логическое ударение, произношение без паузы.

Для логического выделения оборота в предложении применена  **инверсия**, прямой порядок слов такой: они носили тельняшки точно священную реликвию.